# WHY does it need an argument the mock abstract class constructor

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, stub

I am trying mock the `AbstractQuery` class of doctrine

```
    $this->abstractQuery = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery')
                                ->disableOriginalConstructor();
```

Now I will do my stub

```
    $this->abstractQuery->expects($this->at(1))
                        ->method('getResult')
                        ->willReturn('our query result');
```

I getting this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, none given
```

`disabledOriginalConstructor` phpunit's method by default is false

```
/...
public function disableOriginalConstructor()
{
    $this->originalConstructor = false;

    return $this;
}
/...
```

and `getMockForAbstractClass` method it took that value

```
public function getMockForAbstractClass()
{
    $object = $this->generator->getMockForAbstractClass(
        $this->type,
        $this->constructorArgs,
        $this->mockClassName,
        $this->originalConstructor,
        $this->originalClone,
        $this->autoload,
        $this->methods,
        $this->cloneArguments
    );

    $this->testCase->registerMockObject($object);

    return $object;
}
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`disableOriginalConstructor()` is the API of `MockBuilder` class and NOT of class that you get with `$this->getMockForAbstractClass('Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery')`

There are 2 options.

1) First:

Still using method `getMockForAbstractClass`

```
$this->abstractQuery = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(
    'Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery', 
    [], // default value
    '', // default value
    false, // this is $callOriginalConstructor argument
    true, // default value
    true, // default value
    ['getResult'] // here we define methods that we want to mock
);
```

2) Second:

Using `MockBuilder`

```
$this->abstractQuery = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery')
    ->setMethods(['getResult'])
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();
```

I personally prefer MockBuilder because it is more readable.

Comment: `getMock` will get stub about normal class and `getMockForAbstractClass` will get about abstract class, and I think that its position is always in the end setup mock.

Comment: It's possible to set a return value for getResult in your example?

Comment: In my example I create mock, after that you can configure it whatever you like. `$this->abstractQuery->method('getResult')->willReturn('our query result');`

Comment: `setMethods` is now replaced with `onlyMethods`.